# draw routes in open street maps using Python

Tags: python, routes, openstreetmap

I have some latit/longi points and I want to mark different colors for the routes between these points in openstreetmap. How can I do this using python?
Thank you!

Comment: Draw? On an image? On a HTML page? Please describe your problems and goals more detailed.

Comment: On a HTML page.Thanks!

Comment: You don't need python for this. Just take a look at Leaflet or OpenLayers.

Comment: But my data is generated by python programs and they are serialized in .dat file, I should continue using python to finish it. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: You could use python to convert this .dat file into a format readable by Leaflet or OpenLayers, e.g. a GPX file.